# convert Json response to html and apply css

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have response in `json` format from the database as i am using

```
json_encode(result);
```

The response is like

```
[{"restaurant_id":"c3d6","cityname":"Test","resname":"Tomatoes","locname":"Sector 
test","locaddress":"test","locpincode":"123456","locfoodtype":"Indian, 
Chinese","locminorder":"200",}]
```

Now i want to display these values in HTML as in predefined `div` on page
and i am trying like this

```
function makeProdiv(data){
      var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
          var tbl_row = "",
              currRecord = this;
            tbl_row += "<div class=restaurant-header gradient-gray clearfix>";
          $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            if(k==="resname"){
                tbl_row += "<div class=restaurant-title>
               <h2 style=font-size:12px>
               <a href=restodetail?res_id=&location= title=>"+v+"</a></h2>
               <span class=restaurant-title-address style=font-size:10px></span>
               </div></div>";
            }

          })
          tbl_body += tbl_row;
        })

    return tbl_body;
  }
```

The above function is called via ajax

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "page",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(records){
      var result = records.toString();
        if(result==''){
            $('#restodetail').html("<br/><span style=color:red;font-size:16px>Oops!! No Records to show</span>");
        }else{
            $('#restodetail').html(makeProdiv(records));
        }
      }
    });
```

Please let me know how to append to HTML and apply css classes on the json elements

Comment: Take a look at the jquery .append function, in general the jquery docs are a massive help in this case. they even have examples!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g7LEr/ something like this..?

Comment: yes @Bhavik.. but CSS is not getting applied via ajax...css is getting applied if u not calling via ajax [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7LEr/1/)

Comment: @CodeFreak what do u mean by apply css classes? The classes seem to be appended with the html.. what is not working?

Comment: see.. if i have diff sections to display values received in ajax json. i have header class where name of restaurant should be present and address class where address of restaurant should be present. In my way i have to check each `key` value and append html. but i want to access json as `json.resname`